# How to download files off server to localhost

Tags: localhost, filezilla

I just installed XAMMP and set up a localhost on my computer.  I already have a working website and would love to bring all the files  to my localhost on my computer so that I can begin learning how to code and experimenting with code...

Question: how do I bring all the php, mysql files, images, js, etc to my local host?  Do I download all the files into a specific folder such as localhost htdocs folder? or somewhere else?
Is there a tutorial anywhere on the web that someone might know about?

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can download all your files using FTP from your host and place them in your htdocs, but for MySql files you need to export a copy of our database probably by using `yoursite/phpMyadmin` and using the export tab once you have navigated to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use your favorite FTP software and download everything you want available on your localhost. Now head over to the XAMPP installation directory and look for htdocs. Put everything you've downloaded in that directory. Mind that you should keep the directory structure. Should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If you want easily to update the files you do changes on you could use SVN or other version control system (GIT). You could then pull files from your website and edit them and later push changes back to website. If you are interested in this you could use Eclipse as platform and download SVN plugin for it.